# orientation in tabbar application xcode ( ios 5)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

HI All I'm developing tab bar application in which i want to make support to landscape for only first View not for all tabviews , Only one tab should support to all orientations and rest of tabs should support only portrait, i've tried below code in FirstView.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

In secondView.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
return(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

It Does'nt allow me to landscape in any tab view can any 1 help me??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

read about `(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

You need to OR your interfaces, instead of ANDing them.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: Ya i did it it'll work only if secondview.m support to landscape, i don't want like i want work in such a way det only firstview should support to landscape not secondview

Comment: That code needs to be in a subclass of `UIViewController`, not a subclass of `UIView`. Are `firstview` and `secondview` `UIView` subclasses, or are they `UIViewController` subclasses?